# iptables На андроиде

Tags: android, linux, iptables, firewall

Подскажите, на андроиде iptables работает как-то иначе чем на linux? Импортировал с ноута рабочие правила

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1981:543981]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2388:337898]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4041:725149]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3561:440180]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1991:156255]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:478]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1302:116876]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [143:22688]
:oem_nat_pre - [0:0]
:tetherctrl_nat_POSTROUTING - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre
-A POSTROUTING -j tetherctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4041:725149]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4040:725109]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3561:440180]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2504:381402]
COMMIT

# Completed on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -f -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33523 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 2.2.2.2/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 3.3.3.3/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited

COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 22 10:45:54 2022
```

Openvpn connect не работает, в логе
Transport error not resolve DNS
Если изменить политику OUTPUT на ACCEPT и отчистить, то все работает, но это не вариант. Подскажите чего не хватает в цепочке OUTPUT? Нужно чтобы

```
-выход в мнтернет только через vpn туннель
-был доступ к DNS серверу ip 8.8.8.8
-доступ в локалку ip 192.168.0.0/16
-доступ к OpenVPN серверам ip 1.1.1.1/32 2.2.2.2/32 3.3.3.3/32
```